# Extract last dictionary among a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a list of dictionaries, let's say:

```
[{'points':50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010}, 
{'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"}, 
{'points':90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'},
{'points_h1':20, 'month': 'june'}]
```

Is there a way to extract only the last dictionary from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-1 index will give the last element

```
d=[{'points':50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010}, 
    {'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"}, 
    {'points':90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'},
    {'points_h1':20, 'month': 'june'}]
    
    print(d[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also reverse your list  first , then access the first dictionary (which is actually the last dictionary ) .

```
lst_dicts = [{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010},
 {'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"},
 {'points': 90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'},
 {'points_h1': 20, 'month': 'june'}]

res=lst_dicts[::-1] #reversing the list
print(res[0])
```